# Can getters and setters be used more than once?

Tags: java

I have been thinking about it for a long time since i started learning java. I wasn't driven to a situation where I needed this but I'm just curious!

Comment: Best answer: what happens when you try this? You've got a computer programming laboratory at your fingertips, so use it. Experiment, play, write code, run it, change it, push it to the limit and then go beyond, find out what works what doesn't work.

Comment: yes, getters as well as setters can be used more than once

Comment: And yes, there's that answer too

Comment: Thnx guys that was quick!!

Comment: and Hovercraft!! I appreciate your advice!

Comment: Note that this question might not be the best fit for this site as it is one that invites discussion and is better suited for a programming forum, something that this site is not. Please go through the [help] and the [ask] to see how to better use this site. Also, when commenting to an individual, pre-pend the comment with an `@` symbol, e.g., `@hovercraft` or @luksch

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels OK! i'm new here  so i'm really thankful for your guidance!                                                                                                                            (LOVE YOUR USERNAME BTW)

Comment: Getters and setters are just methods, like any other, with particular names and parameters. So, the question is then "can a method be used more than once?". And the answer is: it depends entirely upon how the method was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors can be used once.

Getters and Setters are public methods and be used n number of times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 Object obj = new Object();

 obj.setValue(10); //setter call 1
 obj.setValue(20); //setter call 2
 obj.setValue(30); //setter call 3
 obj.setValue(40); //setter call 4

 System.out.Println(obj.getValue()); // will print 40
}
```

Br,

Rakesh